# Can I remove standard login button from top right on community page

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, login

I have created my custom button in the center of community that redirects user to sign up and login page. I want to hide the one that appears by default on the top right of community page. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot here? Also providing details which template you are using, if your login page is custom built or out of the box, etc. will help.

Comment: I am using "customer service" template.

Comment: The default login button is on the center of the page if you haven't modified it. There's no login button available once the user has logged in. It's still not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS editor in communities.

[image]

[image]

[image]